# Display only child of selected category - Listify/Job Manager

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show the Child of a $selected_category / s  in a multiselect drop down and have tried the following;

```
<?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'name' => 'search_categories',  'selected' => $selected_category, 'child_of' => $selected_category, 'orderby' => 'id','hide_empty' => true) ); ?>
```

You reach the drop down by selecting the parent category on homepage, move to this page showing results.  I want the drop down on this page to only show the child categories of the selected category/s ( as it currently shows all parents and children of all categories)to narrow down the results.  However, although the code I used works on the drop down list perfectly, it removes the parent category and search results of the parent category so displays ALL results  until you select a child category, which isn't ideal.

How can I make the parent category and results remain while showing only the child categories of the selected parent.

surrounding code without the

```
    <?php elseif ( $show_categories && ! is_tax( 'job_listing_category' ) && get_terms( 'job_listing_category' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="search_categories">
            <label for="search_categories"><?php _e( 'Category', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
            <?php if ( $show_category_multiselect ) : ?>
                <?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'name' => 'search_categories',  'selected' => $selected_category,   'child_of' => $selected_category, 'orderby' => 'id','hide_empty' => true) ); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'show_option_all' => __( 'Any category', 'wp-job-manager' ),'orderby' => 'id', 'name' => 'search_categories',  'selected' => $selected_category, 'multiple' => false ) ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/

Comment: you'd be better to ask the plugin/theme author this, without the relevant code the question is impossible to solve.

Answer (score 1):

its has been a long time ago but i needed this and seems like there isnt realy good documentry about it.

add to wp-job-manager-functions.php after line 265(after the function get_job_listing_categories())

```
function get_job_listing_categories_child($id_child) {
    if ( ! get_option( 'job_manager_enable_categories' ) ) {
        return array();
    }

    return get_terms( "job_listing_category", array(
        'orderby'       => 'id',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => true,
        'child_of'        => $id_child,
    ) );
}
```

and if you whant to access the category you can use someting like this:

```
<?php foreach ( get_job_listing_categories_child(86) as $cat ) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cat->term_id ); ?>">
<?php echo esc_html( $cat->name ); ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but then where the 86 is you have to put your id of the head of the childs
To get the id of the head of the child go to your admin panel an click edit on the one you whant.
Then you wil see tag_ID= in the url and the nummer after that is the id that you want to use